# php Как вернуть значение цикла до того как он был вызван?

Tags: php, циклы

Есть вот такой простой код на `php` для примера

```
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
    <div class="copy-block-content _full">
       <div class="names-list _col-<?php echo $counter; ?>">
         <?php
            while (have_rows('column_list')) {the_row();>
             <div class="names-list-item"><?php the_sub_field('column_item'); ?></div>
            <?php $counter++; }  ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Код выводит текст в колонках, в зависимости от количества переменных. Вопрос - как узнать сколько будет итераций (`$counter`) и вернуть это значение в строку `<div class="names-list _col-<?php echo $counter; ?>">` ?

Если у блока было 3 колонки, то в переменной должно быть `<div class="names-list _col-3">` Это вообще возможно ?

Comment: Собирай вывод в цикле в строку. Потом эту строку и выводи.

Comment: Можете показать, пожалуйста, как выводить значение полученое из цикла до его вызова?

Comment: В цикле проходишь по записям и также считаешь их число в `$counter`. Вместо вывода записей - собираешь html в строку. После того как цикл закончился - выводишь и полученное число `$counter` и собранную строку.

Comment: Если я верно понял что нужно, то `get_field('column_list')` -- вернет массив, потому можно просто использовать `count(get_field('column_list'))`.